# Nginx: read temporary cache file

Tags: nginx, cache

I use `ngx_http_proxy_module` with `proxy_ignore_client_abort` to cache files. So when client close connection nginx will continue copying file from backend to current server.

But when another user will try to get this file (which is still copying) nginx will go to backend to get new copy of file and will try to cache it too.

I can use `proxy_cache_lock` to prevent it. But it is bad idea, because file can be very large and it will get much time to wait while file will be cached.

How can I tell nginx to read this temporary file and not wait until the file is cached?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [delivering a stale object](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_use_stale) of the cache. This can be done in case of an error, timeout to the back-end or while updating.

```
proxy_cache_use_stale updating error timeout;
```

Comment: Hm. It will use stale cache file if exists. But when there is no cache file (only tmp) it won't pass tnp file :)

Comment: You can check the upstream_cache_status (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#.24upstream_cache_status) and make an if-block including your exception.